# Can't access AWS EC2 instance after storage expansion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My EC2 instance had 8GB max storage but it was not enough so I decided to expand it to 15GBs (i am using the free tier). I waited process to finish but I lost whatever Access i had to the instance. Connection times out.

I waited several hours more but no change. Accessibility checks are ok and when I choose instance snapshot i see that it stays on the login screen.

Comment: If you didn't allocate an Elastic IP then it likely has a new IP address.  Take a look at the console to get the new address.

Comment: I have allocated Ip. Everything is ok with the IP

Comment: How are you attempting to access the instance? Is it using SSH? Can you use `ssh -v ...` and show us the debug output?

Comment: I get "Connection failed: connection timed out. No more addresses to try.". When search the ip in browser the page loads successfully so the instance is working.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fix my issues - I tried restarting the instance multiple times, I checked the network settings everything was ok there. I changed volumes of the instance and I noticed that the volume maybe was corrupted because the same instance with different volume the SSH was working fine. I ended up setting up a new instance.